# Python, find element in PriorityQueue by value

Tags: python, find, priority-queue

The priority queue PQ stores pairs

```
(weight, element),
```

sorted according to the weight. Does Python's implementation support the search operation in PQ by the element value (element in PQ or not)?

```
PQ = queue.PriorityQueue()
PQ.put((1,2))
PQ.put((5,6))
val = 6
print (val in PQ.queue)       #Nothing has been found
```

I suppose that items in PQ are stored in PQ.queue as tupples.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to search for tuple like (5,6) or just 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

If you want to search for an element:

```
import queue

PQ = queue.PriorityQueue()
PQ.put((1, 2))
PQ.put((5, 6))
val =  4

while not PQ.empty():
   if val in PQ.get():
     print(True)
```

If you want to search for a tuple:

```
import queue

PQ = queue.PriorityQueue()
PQ.put((1, 2))
PQ.put((5, 6))
val = (5, 6)

while not PQ.empty():
  if val == PQ.get():
     print(True)
```

Comment: @ Lakshya: Thanks for your samples. Hence, it is impossible to detect whether PQ contains an element without popping all elements in PQ.

Comment: @justik, that's another question.

Comment: @ Lakshya: Yes, it is, you are right. However, it is common to check the size of the dynamic structure without removing its content.

Comment: you could use custom pqueue or heap or maintain a set for reconstruction with huge tradeoff.

Comment: I tried also heapq, but I am not sure, if it supports any search by element operation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to write a best-frist-search algorithm and ended up the following solution.

```html
from queue import PriorityQueue

def contains_in_pq(pq, node):
    for item in pq.queue:
        if item[1] == node:
            return True
    return False
    
nodes = PriorityQueue()

#Put tuples of (priority and node id) into the p riority queue
nodes.put((99, 1))
nodes.put((98, 2))
nodes.put((96, 3))
nodes.put((100, 4))

print(contains_in_pq(nodes, 1))
print(contains_in_pq(nodes, 4))
print(contains_in_pq(nodes, 4))
print(contains_in_pq(nodes, 0))

while nodes.empty() == False:
    print(nodes.get()[1])

print(contains_in_pq(nodes, 4))


#Outputs:
# True
# True
# True
# False
# 3
# 2
# 1
# 4
# False
```